# Start exe from windows services

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

We have created on windows application, sometimes it is getting crashed, so it stopped from client end. Again user need to start the application manually. If we create windows service, incase the application crashes we can start from exe from service, can anyone help to start the exe from windows services

Comment: Do you try to make some sort of "watchdog" service? Starting process from service is not a problem itself, the question is about process security and user session.

Comment: @Dennis, process getting started, but nothing is working, even program.cs also not getting called if I start the process, it showing in task manager only.

Comment: It's because of how services are related to user sessions and desktops. Your app is shown on service's desktop, and this is not the desktop current interactive user uses. Interactive service (that is, service which could interact with user) is a tricky thing. You didn't answered my question, but I guess I am right. I suggest you to use regular auto-run background application instead of service. This app will start on user logon and will do the same things as you want from the service, but it will do this without all those problems, related to interactive services.

Comment: @Dennis, yes we need kind of watchdog. you suggest to use regular auto-run background application instead of service, means do I need to create one more exe?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes, you need to create one more application, which will run minimized to system tray, and it should have some watchdog timer inside. If on next timer iteration app will detect, that main app was crashed, it will start new main app process.